# Symfony3 amendment of the logger convention

Tags: php, symfony, logging, monolog, symfony3.x

Welcome,

My task is to change the convention of loggers in the application. Currently, loggers are configured as dedicated services. I would like to define the loggers in the Symfony convention and ensure backward compatibility by defining DI directing the old names of logger services to the new ones in the monolog.logger.channel convention. I have the loggers in Symfony do things for the first time or can anyone give me an example of how to do it? Thank you in advance and I greet you below with my current configuration:

app/config/config_dev.yml:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:   stream
            path:   "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level:  debug
            channels: ['!my_channel']
        my_handler:
            type:     stream
            path:     "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.my_handler.log"
            level:    debug
            channels: ['my_channel']
        console:
            type:   console
            bubble: false
```

app/config/config_prod.yml:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler:      nested
            channels: ['!my_channel']
        nested:
            type:  stream
            path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
        console:
            type:  console
        my_channel:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler:      my_channel_stream
        my_channel_stream:
            type:     stream
            path:     "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.my_channel.log"
            level:    debug
            channels: ['my_channel']
```

src/bundle/Resources/config/logger.yml:

```
services:
  logger:
    class: Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger
    arguments: [logger]
    calls:
      - [pushHandler, ['@monolog.handler.console']]
      - [pushHandler, ['@logger_handler']]

  logger_handler:
    class: Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler
    arguments: ["%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.cof.log", 200]
```

src/bundle/Resources/config/config.yml:

```
monolog:
    channels: ['my_channel']
```

Comment: What is the Symfony convention for you? It seems clean to me

Comment: I`m use Symfony 3 and symfony convention for me is http://symfony.com/doc/current/logging/channels_handlers.html